# how can i combine tables on condition base in postgres functions

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT status 
from orders (CASE WHEN true THEN 'INNER JOIN runningmenus ON orders.runningmenu_id = runningmenus.id' ELSE '' END);
```

I am getting error near 'CASE', How can i combine table base on condition?

Comment: You can't have a CASE expression as part of a FROM clause. What exactly are you trying to achieve there? Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Given that the `CASE` condition is true, it implies that you want the join to always happen.  Can you add sample data to your question?

Comment: What's wrong with simply using `from orders join runningmenus on ...`?

Comment: It looks like you either want a join or (if you want to show records that do not match also) a left outer join, case doesn't work that way.

Comment: i only want a conditional based joining of table e.g if condition true then join table else dont do @Lucas

Comment: Sounds as if you are actually looking for an outer join, not an inner join. Where does that "condition" come from? Is that a column in one of the tables?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name condition is coming from a parameter in my procedure that can be true or false

Comment: @MohsinMalik You could always use dynamic sql if you want... `query := 'SELECT status FROM orders' || CASE WHEN ... THEN ' INNER JOIN ... ' ELSE '' END; EXECUTE query;`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a join only if a condition is true.

The trick is to always do the join but to use the parameterized condition in the join condition. Fields from both tables will always be included in the output (which is a good thing, the output is clearly defined) but the data may be set or null.

```
SELECT *
from orders 
INNER JOIN runningmenus 
 ON my_parameter_condition = true AND orders.runningmenu_id = runningmenus.id
```

**Edit** : Following @404 comment, the behavior is a bit more complex. You would have to make a left join and keep rows when the parameter condition is false (== no join) or when the joined table has a matching rown (== an inner join):

```
SELECT *
from orders 
LEFT JOIN runningmenus 
 ON my_parameter_condition = true AND orders.runningmenu_id = runningmenus.id 
WHERE (my_parameter_condition = false OR runningmenus.id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: This is not quite the same as what OP's original code attempts to achieve; by not joining at all if `my_parameter_condition <> TRUE` OP gets *all* records from `orders`, but using your way OP gets *nothing at all* when `my_parameter_condition <> TRUE`. (I was originally gonna suggest this method but then realised it would change the behaviour of the original code.)

Comment: @404 good catch! I believe it can be achieve with a left join + filter then